# selecting all the image sources in a class in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to select all the image sources in a class in jQuery and assign a new src if they meet a certain criteria.

This is how I've started

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{ 
    $('.clear_compare_btn').click(function(event){
        if ($(".myclass").attr("img") == "static/img/compare_checked.png")  {} 
    });
});
```

I'm not sure if the above just checks the first image in elements that contain myclass? How would I check each one and replace the src if the src is "static/img/compare_checked.png" ?

Answer (score 1):

Should it be

```
$('img.myclass').each(function( index ) {
  if ($(this).attr('src') == 'static/img/compare_checked.png') {}
});
```

For how each works:
https://api.jquery.com/each/

Answer (score 0):

Using [each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/):

```
$('.clear_compare_btn').each( function() {
    if ($(this).attr("img") == "static/img/compare_checked.png") {
        //your code here
    }
});
```

Comment: upon clicking .clear_compare_btn, I'm would like to find every img src inside a particular class.... not sure that does that

Comment: I just modified it, just some seconds before @Kyle (thanks :) suggested it in an edit

Comment: but would't that just iterate over the first img only

Comment: It will iterate over all the elements with that class name

Comment: so to add a new src to you would simply write $this.attr("img","new whatever") where "your code here" is ?

Comment: `$(this)`, not `$this`